# How to display left menu using angular tree module with different child and sub child objects keys in JSON

Tags: angularjs

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "node1",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "title": "node1.1",
        "nodess": [
          {
            "id": 111,
            "title": "node1.1.1",
            "nodes": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "title": "node1.2",
        "nodes": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "node2",
    "nodrop": true,
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 21,
        "title": "node2.1",
        "nodes": []
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "title": "node2.2",
        "nodes": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "node3",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 31,
        "title": "node3.1",
        "nodes": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: for reference please check the link https://jsfiddle.net/0uzmoy34/250/

Comment: Fixed the above issue by writing a custom function in the ng-click event handler and in that function created the new nodes and pushed the data to that particular property....

Comment: var nodeData = scope.$modelValue.nodess[0];
      nodeData.nodes.push({
  id: scope.$modelValue.id+ '_' +1 * 10 + nodeData.nodes.length,
  title:'test',
                nodes: []
      });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the above issue by writing a custom function in the ng-click event handler and in that function created the new nodes and pushed the data to that particular property....Example

```
var nodeData = scope.$modelValue.nodess[0];
  nodeData.nodes.push({
    id: scope.$modelValue.id+ '_' +1 * 10 + nodeData.nodes.length,
    title:'test',
    nodes: []
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this awesome library, it has everything for nested json and tree that you need

https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control

Example

```
<div id="treeview" treecontrol class="tree-classic"
     tree-model="slides"
     options="treeOptions"
     selected-node="node"
     on-selection="showSelected(node)"
     filter-expression="node.children.length"
     filter-comparator="comparator"
     expanded-nodes="expandedNodes"
     ng-click="">
    <span>{{node.Title}}</span>
</div>
```

**Controller Stuff**

```
$scope.slides = [];

var treeOptions = {
    nodeChildren: "children",
    dirSelectable: false,
    injectClasses: {
        ul: "a1",
        li: "a2",
        liSelected: "a7",
        iExpanded: "a3",
        iCollapsed: "a4",
        iLeaf: "a5",
        label: "a6",
        labelSelected: "a8"
    },
    isLeaf: function(node) {
        return node.IsSlide;
    },
    allowDeselect: false
}

$scope.node = null; //select a by default node if you want
$scope.expandedNodes = []; //by default expand if you want
```

Check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/imraqes/Lyrzq3er/) out

Comment: @Rakeshchand can you please take the reference of the json and example that I have given in the Question....It seems the above is not useful....

Comment: @SrinivasBabu check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/imraqes/Lyrzq3er/ there i'm using your data